# How to get a response cookie with flurl

Tags: flurl

How to get a response cookie with flurl? I've searched for some references and studied on [flurl.dev](http://flurl.dev) but still confused how to apply them. sorry I am not a programmer, I still have a lot to learn.
Simple code that i use :

```
var strUrl = await url
.WithHeaders(new
{
    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36",
    content_type = "application/json",
    cookie = "cookie"
})
.PostJsonAsync(new
{
    user = "user",
    password = "password"
})
.ReceiveString();
```

**Result : 200 OK**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that when you call `ReceiveString()`, you're getting the response body and effectively discarding the other aspects of the response message returned by `PostJsonAsync`. You can get the response, cookies, and body in separate steps like this:

```
var resp = await url
    .WithHeaders(...)
    .PostJsonAsync(...);
    
var cookies = resp.Cookies; // list of FlurlCookie objects
var body = await resp.GetStringAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks it's perfect